# Android Playing MediaPlayer in SeparateThread

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer

I have a Mp3Link need to play it on my Device in a Separate Thread

I have tried this,But when i execute my code ,I'm not able to play the Music,Could any one look at My Code,What Went Wrong?

Here My Code:

```
Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //code to do the HTTP request
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();  
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  
        try {  
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mp3Link);  
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (SecurityException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();  
        // You can show progress dialog here untill it prepared to play  
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {  
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {  
                // Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing 
                Log.d("Mediaplyer>>>>>>>>", "Mediaplyer>>>>>>>>");
                mp.start();  
            }  
        });  
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {  
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {  
                // dissmiss progress bar here. It will come here when  
                // MediaPlayer  
                // is not able to play file. You can show error message to user  
                return false;  
            }  
        });  

    }
});
trd.start();
```

Comment: Can you please post what is being displayed on the LogCat ?

Comment: No Logcat Error,just not able to play the Audio

Comment: Not necessarily an error (exception), the media player logs a lot about what it does (at least what happens with me).

Answer (score 1):

How about put

```
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

at the end of `run()` function ?

```
Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //code to do the HTTP request
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();  
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  
        try {  
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mp3Link);  
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (SecurityException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        // mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();  // <== Marked
        // You can show progress dialog here untill it prepared to play  
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {  
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {  
                // Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing 
                Log.d("Mediaplyer>>>>>>>>", "Mediaplyer>>>>>>>>");
                mp.start();  
            }  
        });  
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {  
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {  
                // dissmiss progress bar here. It will come here when  
                // MediaPlayer  
                // is not able to play file. You can show error message to user  
                return false;  
            }  
        });  
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // <== Add

    }
});
trd.start();
```

Hope this helps.